# call back method for membase

Tags: key-value-store, membase

Do membase providing any call back method. The requirements is as soon as a value put in to membase, a callback method should get called and it will store the data in to database or any file system. Do membase support this function or is there any other key-value store supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike mentioned I created a hack and used tap stream to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

On the new Couchbase website you now have the ability to download 1.7+ versions of Membase/Couchbase. Also, Membase has been renamed to Couchbase. 1.8.x and lower are the typical Membase architecture. 2.0 and higher versions of Couchbase provide support for documents and querying.

Comment: My requirement is the real time asynchronous call back method (i.e) as soon as the set method called some sort of call back method that I can implement post process asynchronously

Comment: I think I typed this answer into the wrong question. Anyways, I assume you are looking for a callback on the server that you can hook into?

Comment: We don't have any hooks api on the server so in order to do this you would have to hack the code and build it yourself. One thing you can look into though are tap streams. They will stream out all mutations in the server and by inspecting this stream you could most likely accomplish what you wanted to do with a hooks api.